# JasperReports font problem for Indian language

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am designing a report with some marathi (Indian language) words. iReport's internal and HTML preview work. The PDF view, however, does not work.

There may be some error on the PDF side, or may an error in `iText.jar`.

Then i used this java code.
The report uses freesans.ttf font with the following code:

```
JRReportFont font = new JRDesignReportFont();
font.setPdfFontName("FreeSans.ttf");
font.setPdfEncoding(com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
font.setPdfEmbedded(true);
jasperPrint.setDefaultFont(font);
pdfExpoter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
pdfExpoter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
pdfExpoter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, destFile.toString());
pdfExpoter.exportReport();
```

At least it showed the marathi words. But the words are not displayed properly (they break and the alignment is poor).

What must I do to:

- Display the PDF?
- Fix the alignment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is due to `export()` method, in Indic scripts there are some word while printing them we need to move left-right and reverse. this causes the issue.

Somebody has used OpenOffice's exporter and hosted a newer version of Jasper Report , Check it [indic-jasper](http://code.google.com/p/indic-jasper/)

Comment: hi i already used the openoffice's exporter. The problem is that we cant specify the size for field. It takes its own size. If we are adding some extra character (Characters form keyboard), then the allignment is terrible. Overall it looks very ugly. But i wonder how the iReport's inbuilt preview renders it well.

Comment: Then you can check for the lib those are in the classpath of iReport make them available in your app. there are some jars with jasper, for example jasper-fonts which is there by default with iReport will will preview your font Bold,Italic, but when you will export them it won't , So double check for these lib

Comment: But that's i am unable to found out. how the jasper engine is doing?

Comment: i tried to use the font,found at jasper's installation folder. then i tried to use it with java code as earlier i have showed the code. but when i run it fails to get that font.

Comment: Again when i am using openoffice by java code, no font is working, even the freesans.ttf. it is using its own font

Comment: is [this](http://theskeleton.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by-jasperreports/) the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a jar of files under ireport4.0.2/ireport/fonts and add it to your classpath if you get an arror says like "JVM can't find the font".